# Moving image to background?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a game where I move images around.  I have two big images which should have smaller images on top of them.  I often move the smaller images from one of the bigger images onto the other.  However I recently added a feature where the big image gets changed up mid-game.  This caused it to have priority over the smaller images, and when I move the small images, they end up being moved behind the big images.

In short, I always want the big images to be in the background and the small ones to be in the foreground.  Is there a property I can set on those to make this happen?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> If you have more than one user interface element in a particular grid cell, the elements are layered on top of each other. **Elements added earlier in XAML appear below (lower layer) than elements added later.**
>
> You can change the layering of the elements by changing the order in which they are added to the Grid.  **You can also control the layering by giving each element a value for Panel.ZIndex.**  Elements with higher values for ZIndex will appear to be on top of elements with lower values, regardless of the order in which they were added to the Grid.

Source:
http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/zindex/

MSDN page on the ZIndex property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx